# I'm using this script to search multiple tables. the ugly thing is that it cuts the first row

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input",tablefilter)  
}
function tablefilter() {
            // Declare variables
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            tables = document.querySelectorAll(".table");
            
            tables.forEach(function(table) {
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
                        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
                            match = false;
                        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                match = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!match) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
}
```

The ugly thing is that it cuts the first row. How could I solve this? I tried to find a solution in the web, but I found nothing. So I ask here. Thanks for all the help! in this example you can try it by yourself: [example](https://develfabi.wfmedia.ch/ASUS.html)

Comment: Could it be that the first row uses `<th>` elements instead of `<td>` for each cell?

Comment: I tried to change the '<th>' elements to '<td>' . This only works if there is nothing in the search field, as soon as you types something in it, it removes the first row anyway.

Comment: @SandraWeidmann: Can you update the question to include a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Comment: here you can see it by yourself: as you type in the search field it cuts the first row: [link] (https://develfabi.wfmedia.ch/ASUS.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're looping through every "row" in the table:

```
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

The header row is a row.  Presumably this is meant to exclude the header:

```
if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
```

But does your actual HTML include the class `header` in the `<tr>`?  According to the off-site HTML linked from [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172870/im-using-this-script-to-search-multiple-tables-the-ugly-thing-is-that-it-cuts#comment134332933_76172870), it does not.  Add it:

```
<thead>
  <tr class="header">
    ...
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Alternatively, only target rows in the `<tbody>` instead of the entire table:

```
tables.forEach(function(table) {
  const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  tr = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Comment: thanks a lot, adding a `<tr class="header">` was the solution.